# Combine audio from one video file with video from another

Tags: audio, software-recommendation, software

I would like to combine high-resolution video in English with a foreign-language audio track from a low-resolution version of the same movie.

What is good software (for Windows 7) to combine audio from one video file with video (same video content) from another?

Ideally, it would also automatically correct for time offset based on the video content (frame similarity).

Answer (score 1):

IF you have Win7, Movie Maker will do it.

If not, almost every video editing software where you can have more than 1 clip will do it.
If you thinking about doing some more stuff, you could use Hitfilm or Davinci Resolve.

Comment: Which of these can automatically correct for time offset based on the video content (frame similarity)? Which of them are easy to use?

Comment: most will automatically synch video clips based on audio, but not video. You'd have to do that manually - you could just lay the two clips into separate tracks and slip one of them forward or backward until the video synchs up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shutter Encoder](https://www.shutterencoder.com/en/) to do that. It's free, but they did a really good job putting this app together. I've recently started using it in place of other higher profile programs.

It's basically a really nice GUI front end for ffmpeg.

This one will definitely merge video and audio for you, and you can even trim whichever is shorter if you'd like. See if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Does Shutter Encoder automatically correct for time offset based on the video content (frame similarity)?

Comment: I don't know that one, but you can email the dev or go on their Reddit page. They are pretty responsive.